# How to get to via Cesare Balbo 4, 00184 Roma from FCO airport?

Tags: italy, night-transport

I am expected to visit Rome in the next month.
My flight is scheduled to arrive at FCO airport at night 00:30 am.

> How to get to Via Cesare Balbo 4, 00184 Roma from FCO airport at night ?

Is there night bus or trains ?

> Can I wait at the FCO airport untill morning 5 am for trains ?

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Comment: https://www.google.com/maps/dir/Fiumicino,+00054+RM/YWCA-UCDG+Casa+per+ferie,+Via+Cesare+Balbo,+4,+00184+Roma+RM/@41.8376559,12.2415245,11z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m18!4m17!1m5!1m1!1s0x1325fa8154df17fb:0x8d17e9d977b3a688!2m2!1d12.2397117!2d41.7735409!1m5!1m1!1s0x12cdf3ca29fce169:0x8f74867de633b76d!2m2!1d12.4963307!2d41.89976!2m3!6e0!7e2!8j1679446800!3e3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there night bus or trains ? I don't preper taxi because of cheap budget.

The last trains leave around 23:30, so no trains for you

Buses, yes

TAM operates buses leaving at 01:30 and 02:30 ([timetable](https://www.tambus.it/roma-fiumicino/)) for a price of €7 single and €12 return

You can buy the tickets directly [Online](https://tambus.openmove.com/) (Select from Fumicino Aeroporto to Stazione Termini)

And the buses depart from the arrival levels at Terminal 3 (Bus stop 13)

The bus will get you to Rome Termini rail station where it is a 10min walk to your destination

Comment: Thank you very much for help. Can I stay at the airport until 5 am, in case ?