# How can i get from Rome or FCO airport to Napoli in the early hours (1:00 AM to 4:00AM)?

Tags: public-transport, italy, car-rentals, transportation, rome

My flight arrives to FCO airport in Rome around 1 AM and I want to get to Napoli.

I could not find any trains that operate overnight and the earliest bus is at 4 AM.

I also could not find any car rental services that would allow me to pick up the car in Rome and drop it off in Napoli, unless i have missed something.

What would be the best way to get to Napoli from Rome during these early hours?

Thanks!

Comment: What is your criteria, earliest arrival?

Answer (score 2):

> What would be the best way to get to Napoli from Rome during these early hours?

Wait. As you've figured out, this is not really possible, short of a shuttle that will set you back $1000

The bus takes 4h, while the train takes **at most** 3h, I'd strongly recommend the train for that journey.

You can either take a nap in the airport and grab a train from the airport to the central Termini station in the morning to get the 6AM Italo train that arrives at 7AM

Or, you can take a bus to Termini directly (see [this answer](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/180191/118049)) on arrival and maybe get accommodation for that 6AM train and be fully rested before taking it